# Pandas - how to join only of first match and leave other matches as 0

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I want to merge two data frames. It's a left merge, but I don't want to match all instances. I just want to keep the match for the first match and place a 0 for all the other matches.

This is what I have:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| Eticket| Passenger|  Age   | 
+--------+----------+--------+
| ABCD   | 1        | Adult  |
| SDFD   | 1        | Adult  |
| SDFD   | 1        | Child  |
| SDFD   | 1        | Child  |
| WERT   | 1        | Adult  |
| WERT   | 1        | Adult  | 
| ASWD   | 1        | Adult  | 
+--------+----------+--------+
```

I'm trying to consolidate the passenger counts and have it look like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| Eticket| Passenger|  Age   | 
+--------+----------+--------+
| ABCD   | 1        | Adult  |
| SDFD   | 3        | Adult  |
| SDFD   | 0        | Child  |
| SDFD   | 0        | Child  |
| WERT   | 2        | Adult  |
| WERT   | 0        | Adult  | 
| ASWD   | 1        | Adult  | 
+--------+----------+--------+


passenger_group = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by='Eticket')['Passenger'].sum())
```

I'm easily able to create a table that generates a count per Eticket, but when I attempt to merge it obviously looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| Eticket| Passenger|  Age   | 
+--------+----------+--------+
| ABCD   | 1        | Adult  |
| SDFD   | 3        | Adult  |
| SDFD   | 3        | Child  |
| SDFD   | 3        | Child  |
| WERT   | 2        | Adult  |
| WERT   | 2        | Adult  | 
| ASWD   | 1        | Adult  | 
+--------+----------+--------+
```

How do I join these two data frames (or even use some alternative method) to get the desired output?

Comment: Used some table formatting tool, no IDE sorry, just pure tedious manual edits

Answer (score 2):

I am using `transform` sum and assign it back by using `duplicated`

```
df.loc[~df.Eticket.duplicated(),'New']=df.groupby('Eticket').Passenger.transform('sum')
df.New.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df
  Eticket  Passenger    Age  New
0    ABCD          1  Adult  1.0
1    SDFD          1  Adult  3.0
2    SDFD          1  Child  0.0
3    SDFD          1  Child  0.0
4    WERT          1  Adult  2.0
5    WERT          1  Adult  0.0
6    ASWD          1  Adult  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you transform the sum

```
df['Passenger'] = df.groupby(by='Eticket')['Passenger'].transform(sum)
```